# QSortFilterProxyModel: index from wrong model passed to mapToSource - why?

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm getting this in my application output and can't figure out the problem.  My code, which is in a subclass of QTableView, with model() returning a QSortFilterProxyModel:

```
  const QSortFilterProxyModel *proxy = dynamic_cast<const QSortFilterProxyModel*>(model());
  QModelIndex proxy_index2 = proxy->index(row, column, QModelIndex());
  QModelIndex model_index = proxy->mapToSource(proxy_index2);
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using Qt 4.7.

Edit:

I'm not sure what's going on, but this code is working fine now.  I did check that the index is valid, then just proceeded for the time being.  I'm not sure what I changed that fixed the problem, but the code above is working fine at this point.

It would be helpful to know what fixed the problem of course so I can understand how to use Qt better, but I'd probably have to give you guys the rest of my code at the point when I saw the problem - and I have no copy of the code in that state.  So, I guess it will have to remain a mystery unless I run into it again!  Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that proxy_index2 is always a valid QModelIndex?

Comment: Additionally, are you sure that row and column are in the valid range for the proxy model?  Otherwise, an invalid index is returned, and then passed to mapToSource().

Comment: Hi, you subclass QTableView in a strange way. I suppose that if you call setModel(myModel), then model() does not return myModel, but a QSortFilterProxyModel that you created on myModel. This is not an usual way of sorting items : either implement sorting fully internally in the QTableView, without exposing the sort model, or fully externally, by creating the sort model outside the class and connecting it via setModel()
You should add checks for row, columns everywhere.